# Limit Of Function Composition

Tags: calculus, proof-verification

> Let there be $g(x)$ and $f(x)$ two functions define on $\mathbb{R}$.
>   
>   And $$lim_{x \to a} f(x)=b$$ $$lim_{y \to b} g(y)=c$$
>   
>   moreover, $$\ h(y) := \left\{ 
>   \begin{array}{l l}
>     g(y) & \quad \text{if $y\neq b$ }\\
>     c & \quad \text{if $y=b$ }
>   \end{array} \right.$$
>   
>   prove: $$lim_{x\to a}h(f(x))=c$$

$lim_{x\to a}h(f(x))=h(lim_{x\to a}f(x))=h(x\to b)$ if x=b so we are done, else $h(x)=g(x)\rightarrow c$.

What should I add about the limit of function composition? are there are more details that are lacking in the proof?

Comment: How do you know $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} h(f(x)) = h(\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x))$?  That one step is essentially what the question is asking to be proved.

Comment: yes indeed!!! you are not given that $h$ is continuous so you can not take the limit inside the argument of $h$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\epsilon > 0$.

There is $\delta> 0$ such as:
$$
0 < |y - b| < \delta \implies |g(y) - c|<\epsilon
$$

From that:
$$
|y - b| < \delta \implies |h(y) - c|<\epsilon
$$

Now using the fact that $\lim_a f = b$, you can find $\eta> 0$  such as
$$
|x - a| < \eta \implies |f(x) - b|<\delta
$$
You just have to combine these two inequlities now:
\begin{align}
|x - a| < \eta &\implies |f(x) - b|<\delta \\
&\overset{y = f(x)}{\implies}  
|h(f(x)) - c| <\epsilon
\end{align}

Comment: shouldn't I check the continuity of $h$?

Comment: This is why I did, implicitely.